What is the probability that $n$ uniformly distributed random variables fall within a distance of $\frac{1}{c}$ of each other?
Consider random variables $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n$ that are IID following a uniform distribution $\text{Unif}(0, 1)$.
What is the probability that the following event occurs:
$$
|X_1 - X_2| < \frac{1}{c}, \quad |X_1 - X_3| < \frac{1}{c}, \quad \ldots, \quad |X_{n-1} - X_n| < \frac{1}{c}?
$$
After trying to figure this out I have come to the conclusion that I need to calculate the ration of a volume in $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $1$, but I can not find this area for general n. For $n=2$ this volume appears to be $1 - (1 - \frac{1}{c})^2$. For the case of $n=3$ I have worked out that the probability should be $\frac{1}{6c^3}*(9c-4)$ but my simulation seems to disagree.
Any help on the general case, or even on the case of $n=3$ would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

The second one should be $|X_2 - X_3|$, right?

This should be relevant: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4740702/distribution-of-the-largest-gap-between-uniform-random-variables

What if you define $Y=\min[X_1, ..., X_n]$ and you condition on $Y$ being a value $y \in [0,1]$? Note the cases $y<1-1/c$ and $y\geq 1-1/c$ can be treated separately.

Check this out: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2001026/321264. Your probability is \begin{align}
P\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^{n-1} \left{|X_i-X_{i+1}|< \frac1c\right}\right)
&=1-P\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^{n-1} \left{|X_i-X_{i+1}|> \frac1c\right}\right)
\&=1-P\left(\min\limits_{1\le i\le n-1}|X_i-X_{i+1}| > \frac1c \right).
\end{align}
